# Export Database From JPA Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hello I have Mysql/Mariadb Server That need to export database with all Table structure and data in it. I connected with JPA with xml config file , that need to export all Table structure and data with this connection and not execute some SSH/CMD command for export database, How can be done this?

My JPA Connection is :

```
public class HibernateConnection {


    private static HibernateConnection instance;
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private HibernateConnection() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-connection-ca-local");
    }

    public static synchronized HibernateConnection getInstance() {
        return instance == null ? instance = new HibernateConnection() : instance;
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        if (entityManagerFactory != null) {
            entityManagerFactory.close();
            instance = null;
        }
    }


}
```

I need just export a Single file (.sql) for all create and insert Tables.
If all tables goes into multiple file no matter and is good for me.
Thanks all Stackoverflow users.